# Ethics in social encounter by individuals protected from low quality products

Tags: ethics

Given a bad situation in a business interaction what do the systems of ethics say about the interactions? What are the ethics involved in social encounters by individuals protected from low quality products?

- Should the goal be zero sum that both parties leave with what they
  came with?
- Should one party be favored in the outcome?
- What about when goods are not being exchanged but services? When a
  service is inadequate but complete who should be paid and how much?
- What about when injury is involved to one party like bad medical devices or service?

My ethical dilemma is that I often find that good and services are not adequate to the standards of american life. Someone from a poorer country might view the service and business as above their quality standard but there is no way it would match their price point. That is to say the places around me in Illinois and in general on ebay and amazon are trying to rip me off and steal my money either by providing me broken items without disclosing the feature which is broken and allowing me to find it later or by proving sub par service by hiring only the minimal amount of people to perform service and not maintaining their places of business where I'm supposed to be enjoying myself. My main concern is the ethics of charge reversals when the merchant does not want the charge reversal but clearly failed to meet common standards. (then generalizing to things like FDIC and the like)

Comment: Could you make it clearer what specifically you believe the ethical question is? I'm having trouble deciphering quite what the issue is... so far it sounds like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwvlbJ0h35A without any ethical principle behind them.

Comment: @virmaior uh well i dont really think this is first world problems as people were sold horses with bad teeth a long time ago

Comment: @virmaior the question is ethically how should the encounter happen?

Comment: is the intervention by a third party to remedy the situation unethical?

Comment: At the simplest level, what is the question? (Skip the poor country thing) Is the question, "are chargebacks every ethical to do?" or ???

Comment: @virmaior its not just chargebacks but all things like fdic and the like

Comment: so you're question is about whether there should be consumer protections?

Comment: @virmaior more like by what ethical standard should consumer protections be set

Comment: that's an extremely complex question. You could simplify it for us if you say what sort of ethical theory you ascribe to. Otherwise, you're just going to get *non sequitur* answers

Comment: @virmaior why they would respond with quotes from a good voyager episode idk but I don't know what exact ethical theories I subscribe too :)

Comment: Ethics according to who? Your cultural ethics, the other country's cultural ethics, whose ethics? Besides, ethical business is an oxymoron.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I'm sorry you do not believe in the science of ethics

Comment: I believe in ethics, but what is considered ethics varies from culture to culture. Big businesses have tried to foster this concept of "business ethics", but it is just another way to make you feel good about them.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda no your referring to morals not ethics in general and just like there is Newtonian and quantum and string physics there are many different kinds of science which study ethics

Comment: ? - According to Websters, ethics is defined as "moral principles that govern a person's or group's behavior".......

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda i'm sorry english is a fickle language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_ethics is the more universally understood and accepted branch of the science but you can read in general http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics

Comment: morals tend to be caused by religious organisation while ethics tend to be derived from principles of nature. morals are truth based while ethics are facts based.

Comment: truths normally have no acception or only extreme exception but facts change as the environment and situation changes.